# TYPO3 v8 how can i change default rte from ckeditor back to rtehtmlarea?

Tags: typo3, rte

I installed rtehtmlarea from https://github.com/FriendsOfTYPO3/rtehtmlarea (i use typo3 v8.7.8). Now, how do i set it to be default rte ? In my User Settings -> Edit and Advanced functions -> Enable Rich Text Editor (if available) is checked. Also i tried changing `RTE.default.disabled = 1` as in [documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/Rte/Transformations/Tsconfig/Index.html#examples) without success. Is it relevant, or is there other settings i need to be looking at?

Comment: in extension manager, have you disabled rte_ckeditor?

Comment: @Riccardo De Contardi You are right, you need to disable rte_ckeditor. Now i tried it again and it worked. Before i have got an error, which looked something like this 'Can't load Yaml configuration EXT:rte_ckeditor/...path to default conf.yaml'. (I have been using custom RTE Yaml configuration, but i am sure i disabled it in ext_localconf, reinstaled my plugin and then disabled rte_ckeditor).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) Unload extension rte_ckeditor - rtehtmlarea will then kick in

b) Raise the priority of $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['formEngine']['nodeResolver'][1480314091]['priority'] (this is the htmlarea element resolver) above 50 (higher than the ckeditor resolver priority which is 50) to take precendence - see the two form element resolver registrations in ext_localconf.php of ext:rtehtmlarea and ext:rte_ckeditor

c) If you want ckeditor in some places and htmlarea in others depending on edited element (table / record type / ...): Add an own resolver with priority higher than 50 and do your magic in there. See \TYPO3\CMS\RteCKEditor\Form\Resolver\RichTextNodeResolver and \TYPO3\CMS\Rtehtmlarea\Form\Resolver\RichTextNodeResolver as examples on how to do that.

The FormEngine resolvers are also documented at https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ApiOverview/FormEngine/Rendering/Index.html#nodefactory

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer and Node factory link. Problem was in disabling all reference to rte_ckeditor (in my case custom rte setup).